# Nested loops with arrays not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to accomplish the following...

Given the array cakes as:

```js
const cakes = [
    {id: 1, name: 'chocolate'},
    {id: 2, name: 'strawberry'},
    {id: 3, name: 'mint'}
]
```

And the array 'favorite cakes' as:

```js
const favCakes = [
    {id: 1, cakeId: 1},
    {id: 2, cakeId: 2}
]
```

I want to log FAVORITE CAKES and NOT FAVORITE CAKES on console so I would expect a result like this:

```
FAVORITE CAKES: 'chocolate'
FAVORITE CAKES: 'strawberry'
NOT FAVORITE CAKES: 'mint'
```

But it does't work as expected as you can see from the snippet below. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help.

```js
const cakes = [
    {id: 1, name: 'chocolate'},
    {id: 2, name: 'strawberry'},
    {id: 3, name: 'mint'}
]

// favorite cakes for logged in user
const favCakes = [
    {id: 1, cakeId: 1},
    {id: 2, cakeId: 2}
]

for (const cake of cakes) {
    for (const fav of favCakes) {
        if (cake.id === fav.cakeId) {
            console.log('FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name )
        }
        else if (cake.id !== fav.cakeId) {
            console.log('NOT FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of whether the cake was found in your favorites list. Then, after looking through all the favorites, you can report on whether it was found.

```js
const cakes = [
    {id: 1, name: 'chocolate'},
    {id: 2, name: 'strawberry'},
    {id: 3, name: 'mint'}
]

// favorite cakes for logged in user
const favCakes = [
    {id: 1, cakeId: 1},
    {id: 2, cakeId: 2}
]

for (const cake of cakes) {
    let foundAsFavorite = false
    
    for (const fav of favCakes) {
        if (cake.id === fav.cakeId) {
            foundAsFavorite = true
        }
    }

    if (foundAsFavorite) {
        console.log('FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name )
    }
    else {
        console.log('NOT FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name )
    }
}
```

Here's a simpler solution that uses the `Array.some` function to find out if any favorites match your cake:

```js
const cakes = [
    {id: 1, name: 'chocolate'},
    {id: 2, name: 'strawberry'},
    {id: 3, name: 'mint'}
]

// favorite cakes for logged in user
const favCakes = [
    {id: 1, cakeId: 1},
    {id: 2, cakeId: 2}
]

for (const cake of cakes) {
    const foundAsFavorite = favCakes.some(fav => cake.id === fav.cakeId)

    if (foundAsFavorite) {
        console.log('FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name )
    }
    else {
        console.log('NOT FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are checking for not-favorites too early. You can only determine not-favorites after you have looked through all the favorites:

```
for (const cake of cakes) {
    let isFavorite = false; // assume

    for (const fav of favCakes) {
        if (cake.id === fav.cakeId) {
            console.log('FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name)
            isFavorite = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! isFavorite ) {
        console.log( 'NOT FAVORITE CAKE: ', cake.name )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `forEach` & `find`. Use `forEach` to iterate the `cakes` array and use its id to find the object with same `id` in `favCakes`. If the `id` matches then log the name with favorite else with not favorite

```js
const cakes = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'chocolate'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'strawberry'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'mint'
  }
]

const favCakes = [{
    id: 1,
    cakeId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cakeId: 2
  }
]

cakes.forEach((item) => {
  const isFav = favCakes.find(elem => elem.id === item.id)
  if (isFav) {
    console.log('Fav cake ', item.name)
  } else {
    console.log('Not Fav cake ', item.name)
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it nested - use a method such as `some` inside a `forEach` instead, and simplify with destructuring:

```js
const cakes = [
    {id: 1, name: 'chocolate'},
    {id: 2, name: 'strawberry'},
    {id: 3, name: 'mint'}
]

// favorite cakes for logged in user
const favCakes = [
    {id: 1, cakeId: 1},
    {id: 2, cakeId: 2}
]

cakes.forEach(({ id, name }) => {
    if (!favCakes.some(({ cakeId }) => cakeId == id)) {
      console.log("NOT FAVOURITE CAKE: " + name);
    } else {
      console.log("FAVOURITE CAKE: " + name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a lookup list like this.

```
    const cakes = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'chocolate'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'strawberry'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'mint'
      }
    ];

    // favorite cakes for logged in user
    const favCakes = [{
        id: 1,
        cakeId: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        cakeId: 2
      }
    ];

    const favCakeIds = favCakes.map(c => c.cakeId);

    for (const cake of cakes) {
      if (favCakeIds.includes(cake.id)) {
        console.log('FAVORITE CAKE: ' + cake.name)
      } else {
        console.log('NOT FAVORITE CAKE: ' + cake.name)
      }
    }
```